# Chrome Extension - How enable read and data permissions in my extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need help with a single, simple question.

In the options "Can read and change site data" reading is disabled for all sites, only when I click, it does not serve my extension.

How can I configure my extension to have this permission.

I will attach prints for the best visualization and my manifest.json. Someone can help me!?

**I need this option**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPfa7.png)

**But this option is disabled**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWKSv.png)

**My manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Bit Tabs",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "Extensão para monitorar abas em inatividade no navegador",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "optional_host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"]
}
```

I just want to enable these options to ensure my extension works correctly

Comment: Remove `optional_`. Also remove the first three items, so that only `"<all_urls>"` remains.